# NullPointerException error when trying to find last item's value in a linked list

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, linked-list

I'm still a beginner in Java - I'm trying to create a method that finds the value of the last item in a linked list, and it's throwing a `java.lang.NullPointerException` error, and it indicates the error is on line 21. From my understanding, a null pointer exception happens when the programmer is calling a reference-type variable to reference basically nothing, since the variable hasn't been declared yet.

For example, if I write `Integer k;`, I cannot call on `k` until I declare: `k = new Integer(10);`. If I write `int k;`, Java automatically sets the value to 0, since it's a primitive type, and I will be able to call it directly.

In this case, I kind of understand why it's throwing this error, since as you can see in the second line of the `getLast()` method, I called next, which should be `null`, since it hasn't been declared yet. However, it's indicating that the error is on line 21, where I reassign `last`. Why?

How do I fix this code? FYI this is just a practice problem through my school's website, and the task was to complete the `getLast()` method.

```
/*
 * Class for representing a linked list of ints.
 */
public class List {
    public int value;
    public List next;

    public List(final int setValue) {
        value = setValue;
    }

    /**
     * Return the value of the last item in the list.
     */
    public int getLast() {
        List current = next;
        int last = next.value;
        while(next != null) {
            current = next;
            next = current.next;
            last = next.value;       //ERROR
        }
        return last;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does ```next``` mean? Why does ```getLast``` method change ```next```?

Comment: @zhh `next` is the next node in the list; technically it's a "sub-list" whose first item is the "next" item in the linked list. The `getLast` method reassigns `next` to `current`, in order to check if it's `null` in the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the statement that moves to the last node as the last statement of the *while* loop so that on the next iteration, the loop condition would become false and the loop terminates. In your case, you try to access the `next` element after you reach the end of the list.

Also, you must use the local variable `current` for iterating and not *assign* / change the *instance variable* `next`. If you call `getLast` the next time, it won't work because `next` now points to `null`.

Change it as

```
List current = next;
int last = value;//Set to the current value to begin with
while(current != null) {
   last = current.value;
   current = current.next;
}
return last;
```

Comment: The initial value of ```last``` should be ```value```.

Comment: @zhh Sorry. I don't get you. It will be set inside the loop(`last = current.value`). If list is empty then 0 will be returned here..

Comment: List cannot be empty because ```this``` itself is a list element.

Comment: @zhh Oh. Just realized that. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, your code worked. I'd like to point out that my code still works when I move the assignment `last = next.value` to the first line of the while loop; but like you said, if I do call `getLast()` again, it would result in an error since `next` is now `null`.

Answer (score 0):

When the while loop gets to the last node you set next to null with:

```
next = current.next
```

You should be able to fix by setting `last = current` instead of next.

But you should be careful about empty lists. It seems that if you called getLast() on an empty list you'd have a NullPointerException again.

Answer (score 0):

`NullPointerException` is thrown because `next` is `null` and you reference `next.value`.

You should not change `next`, use a temporary value to iterate to the end of the list.

```
public int getLast() {
    if (next == null)
        return value;
    List current = next;
    while (current.next != null)
        current = current.next;
    return current.value;
}
```